# Reopen question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [Can a caller abort an execution of code invoked by HTTP request?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/362187/26494), is IMO clearly asking about the network architect and whether a clients actions can effect what is in process on the server.

The question was closed as unclear. I have edited it in the hope of removing any ambiguity, and believe it should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at the edits, it appeared to be improved so I reopened the question.